# Creating a mean value column X using values from column Y IF there is a duplicate in column Z

Tags: r, excel, duplicates, mean

I have a dataset for bird captures where each row is an individual capture event. Individuals are identified by a unique band number (column Z), so if the same individual is captured multiple times  there are duplicates in column Z representing those multiple captures. At each capture (in each row) there is a wing measurement (column Y). Values in column Y can be different for recaptured birds. I want to create a new column (column X) that gives a mean wing value for each individual bird, by taking the mean of all wing values assigned to that band number (column Z) at different captures (multiple rows).

Is there a way to do this in r or in excel?

Answer (score 0):

With dplyr:

```
library(dplyr)
# Given your database is `df` with columns (Y, Z) 

df <- df |> group_by(Z) |> mutate(Y_mean = mean(Y)) |> ungroup()
```